# Python Itertools permutations only letters and numbers

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I need to get only the permutations that have letters and numbers (The permutation can not be. "A, B, C, D" I need it like this: "A, B, C, 1")

In short, the permutations can not contain only letters, not just numbers. Must be a combination of both.

My code:

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.combinations([0,1,2,3,4,'a','b','c','d'], 4))
```

Then I get:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 4), (0, 1, 2, 'a'), (0, 1, 2, 'b'), (0, 1, 2, 'c'), (0, 1, 2, 'd'), (0, 1, 3, 4), (0, 1, 3, 'a'), (0, 1, 3, 'b'), (0, 1, 3, 'c'), (0, 1, 3, 'd'), (0, 1, 4, 'a'), (0, 1, 4, 'b'), (0, 1, 4, 'c'), (0, 1, 4, 'd'), (0, 1, 'a', 'b'), (0, 1, 'a', 'c'), (0, 1, 'a', 'd'), (0, 1, 'b', 'c'), (0, 1, 'b', 'd'), (0, 1, 'c', 'd'), (0, 2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 3, 'a'), (0, 2, 3, 'b'), (0, 2, 3, 'c'), (0, 2, 3, 'd'), (0, 2, 4, 'a'), (0, 2, 4, 'b'), (0, 2, 4, 'c'), (0, 2, 4, 'd'), (0, 2, 'a', 'b'), (0, 2, 'a', 'c'), (0, 2, 'a', 'd'), (0, 2, 'b', 'c'), (0, 2, 'b', 'd'), (0, 2, 'c', 'd'), (0, 3, 4, 'a'), (0, 3, 4, 'b'), (0, 3, 4, 'c'), (0, 3, 4, 'd'), (0, 3, 'a', 'b'), (0, 3, 'a', 'c'), (0, 3, 'a', 'd'), (0, 3, 'b', 'c'), (0, 3, 'b', 'd'), (0, 3, 'c', 'd'), (0, 4, 'a', 'b'), (0, 4, 'a', 'c'), (0, 4, 'a', 'd'), (0, 4, 'b', 'c'), (0, 4, 'b', 'd'), (0, 4, 'c', 'd'), (0, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (0, 'a', 'b', 'd'), (0, 'a', 'c', 'd'), (0, 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 'a'), (1, 2, 3, 'b'), (1, 2, 3, 'c'), (1, 2, 3, 'd'), (1, 2, 4, 'a'), (1, 2, 4, 'b'), (1, 2, 4, 'c'), (1, 2, 4, 'd'), (1, 2, 'a', 'b'), (1, 2, 'a', 'c'), (1, 2, 'a', 'd'), (1, 2, 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 'b', 'd'), (1, 2, 'c', 'd'), (1, 3, 4, 'a'), (1, 3, 4, 'b'), (1, 3, 4, 'c'), (1, 3, 4, 'd'), (1, 3, 'a', 'b'), (1, 3, 'a', 'c'), (1, 3, 'a', 'd'), (1, 3, 'b', 'c'), (1, 3, 'b', 'd'), (1, 3, 'c', 'd'), (1, 4, 'a', 'b'), (1, 4, 'a', 'c'), (1, 4, 'a', 'd'), (1, 4, 'b', 'c'), (1, 4, 'b', 'd'), (1, 4, 'c', 'd'), (1, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 'a', 'b', 'd'), (1, 'a', 'c', 'd'), (1, 'b', 'c', 'd'), (2, 3, 4, 'a'), (2, 3, 4, 'b'), (2, 3, 4, 'c'), (2, 3, 4, 'd'), (2, 3, 'a', 'b'), (2, 3, 'a', 'c'), (2, 3, 'a', 'd'), (2, 3, 'b', 'c'), (2, 3, 'b', 'd'), (2, 3, 'c', 'd'), (2, 4, 'a', 'b'), (2, 4, 'a', 'c'), (2, 4, 'a', 'd'), (2, 4, 'b', 'c'), (2, 4, 'b', 'd'), (2, 4, 'c', 'd'), (2, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (2, 'a', 'b', 'd'), (2, 'a', 'c', 'd'), (2, 'b', 'c', 'd'), (3, 4, 'a', 'b'), (3, 4, 'a', 'c'), (3, 4, 'a', 'd'), (3, 4, 'b', 'c'), (3, 4, 'b', 'd'), (3, 4, 'c', 'd'), (3, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (3, 'a', 'b', 'd'), (3, 'a', 'c', 'd'), (3, 'b', 'c', 'd'), (4, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (4, 'a', 'b', 'd'), (4, 'a', 'c', 'd'), (4, 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
```

I pushing this question, let me know if there is a possible way of knowing the size of the file obtained, if I want to save to a text file. I also want to know if there is any way to calculate how long it would take to get all permutations'm asking.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Nice question. I am actually thinking.

Comment: [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter)? You can work out how many matching permutations there are analytically.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do not quite understand that filter would have to use

Comment: @jcrashvzla ...what?

Comment: The title of your question is about [**permutations**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), while `itertools.combinations` gives subsequences. If you don't consider the order of the sub-sequences, this function yields all possible  [**combinations**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). I guess you probably want 'all combinations of length 4, which have at least 1 letter and at least 1 number'. You might make your question a bit clearer.

Comment: @BasSwinckels exactly, I ask my apologies, I did not speak very good English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using set intersection:

```
import itertools
import string
numbers = set(range(10))
letters = set(string.ascii_letters)
print([x for x in itertools.combinations([0,1,2,3,4,'a','b','c','d'], 4)
       if set(x) & letters and set(x) & numbers])
```

Answer (score 4):

Quite a naive solution..

```
(x
    for x in itertools.combinations([0,1,2,3,4,'a','b','c','d'], 4)
    if not all(c.isalpha() for c in x) and not all(c.isdigit() for c in x))
```

Comment: Note that the integer values are actually ints, not numeric characters, so this will fail trying to evaluate `isalpha()` or `idigit()` on integer values.  Changing to use `isinstance` tests will clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist=[]
for x in permutations([0,1,2,"a","b","c"],4):
    print (x)
    mylist.append(x)
for t in permutations([3,4,"c","d"]):
    print (t)
    mylist.append(t)
```

I split them 3 digit-3letter, 2digit-2letter. So compile *t* and *x* is your answer.First *for* loop cant contain only numbers or only letters because its permutations 4. Second one cant also same reason.So compile the results in a list, means your answer.

> How to calculate the time;

```
import time
mylist=[]
start=time.time()
for x in permutations([0,1,2,"a","b","c"],4):
    print (x)
    mylist.append(x)
for t in permutations([3,4,"c","d"]):
    print (t)
    mylist.append(t)
end=time.time()
diff=end-start
print ("It took",diff,"seconds")
```

Output:

```
...
...
...
('c', 4, 'd', 3)
('c', 'd', 3, 4)
('c', 'd', 4, 3)
('d', 3, 4, 'c')
('d', 3, 'c', 4)
('d', 4, 3, 'c')
('d', 4, 'c', 3)
('d', 'c', 3, 4)
('d', 'c', 4, 3)
It took 0.5800008773803711 seconds
>>>
```

**Edit for how much permutations are there**:

```
from itertools import permutations
import time
mylist=[]
start=time.time()
for x in permutations([0,1,2,"a","b","c"],4):
    print (x)
    mylist.append(x)
for t in permutations([3,4,"c","d"]):
    print (t)
    mylist.append(t)
end=time.time()
diff=end-start
print ("There is {} permutations.".format(len(mylist)))
print ("It took",diff,"seconds")
```

Output:

```
...
...
...
('d', 3, 4, 'c')
('d', 3, 'c', 4)
('d', 4, 3, 'c')
('d', 4, 'c', 3)
('d', 'c', 3, 4)
('d', 'c', 4, 3)
There is 384 permutations.
It took 0.5120010375976562 seconds
>>>
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fast.py", line 4, in <module>
    for x in permutations([0,1,2,"a","b","c"],4):
NameError: name 'permutations' is not defined ?

Comment: You should import it, didnt you?

Comment: How does this generate valid combinations like `(0, 1, 'c', 'd')` or `(3, 4, 'a', 'b')`?

Comment: @jcrashvzla if this answer is correct your question is wrong, as Bas has pointed out

Comment: This approach is inherently flawed - even if you get it to work, it will be very specific to your input set and number of samples in your permutations. Better answers are the ones submitted by BlackBear and jterrace, as they are not as dependent on the data set or permutation size.

Answer (score 0):

Update the valid_data_types_in_list() function to add additional constraints on your list.

```
def valid_data_types_in_list(input_list):
    str_type = False
    int_type = False
    for element in input_list:
        if type(element) == str:
            str_type = True
        if type(element) == int:
            int_type = True
    if str_type == int_type == True:
        return True
    return False

import itertools
output = [x for x in list(itertools.combinations([0,1,2,3,4,'a','b','c','d'], 4)) if valid_data_types_in_list(x)]
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

To use filter or ifilter, you must pass a predicate function and a sequence.  The predicate function is evaluated once for each element in the sequence, and filter will only forward those elements which evaluate the predicate as True.

For instance, let's say you wanted only the uppercase letters in a string:

```
>>> def is_upper(c):
...     return c.upper() == c
...
>>> uppers = filter(is_upper, "lsjdfLSKJDFLljsdlfkjLSFLDJ")
>>> print uppers
LSKJDFLLSFLDJ
```

Or if you only wanted the numbers that end in "6" in some list of numbers:

```
>>> nums_that_end_in_6 = filter(lambda n: n % 10 == 6, range(100))
>>> print nums_that_end_in_6
[6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96]
```

(If you are not used to using lambdas, they are useful with filter when the logic is this simple. The lambda above is the same as:

```
def predicate(n):
    return n % 10 == 6

nums_that_end_in_6 = filter(predicate, range(100))
```

In your situation, you are getting a sequence of combinations of letter and int values, and you only want those that are a mixture of letters and ints.  So you will need to write a predicate function that returns True when given a sequence that is to your liking.  Using the set-based solution, your predicate might look like:

```
ints = set(range(10))
letters = set(string.letters)
def predicate(seq):
    seqset = set(seq)
    return seqset & letters and seqset & ints
```

Using the any/all builtins, your predicate might look like:

```
is_int = lambda x : isinstance(x, int)
is_str = lambda x : isinstance(x, str)
def predicate(seq):
    return not(all(is_int(item) for item in seq) or all(is_str(item) for item in seq))
```

Or if you just want to see if your sequence contains items of more than 1 type, you could write:

```
def predicate(seq):
    return len(set(type(item) for item in seq))) > 1
```

To use any of these predicates, the form is the same:

```
values = list(string.letters) + range(10)
mixed_letter_int_combinations = filter(predicate, combinations(values, 4))
```

Then you can choose which predicate you prefer, based on performance, or readability, or whatever other criteria you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the proper combinations by combining non-empty combinations from the two sequences.

```
import itertools

def combinations(a, b, n):
    for i in xrange(1, n):
        for ca in itertools.combinations(a, i):
            for cb in itertools.combinations(b, n-i):
                yield ca + cb

for r in combinations(list('abcd'), [1, 2, 3, 4], 4):
    print r
```

The number of combinations you get is choose(A+B, n) - choose(A, n) - choose(B, n), where A is the number of elements in a, B the number of elements in b, and "choose" is the binomial coefficient.